# How to reverse nested lists in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, reverse, nested-lists

Consider:

```
(define (nested-reverse lst)
(cond ((null? lst) '())
    ((list? (car lst)) (nested-reverse (car lst)))
    (else
     (cons (nested-reverse (cdr lst))
           (list (car lst))))))
```

When I input,

```
 (nested-reverse '((a b c) 42))
```

it gives me `((() 42) (a b c))`. It's supposed to give me `(42 (c b a))`. How I would change my code so that the nested lists also get reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a list `(1 2 3)` is `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`. Using `append` is a very poor choice on how to reverse a list since `append` is implemented like this:

```
(define (append lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1) (append (cdr lst1) lst2))))
```

A list can be iterated from the first element towards the end while it can only be made in reverse. Thus the obvious none recursive reverse would look like something like this:

```
(define (simple-reverse lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (result '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        result
        (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) result)))))
```

To make it work for nested list you check if you need to reverse `(car lst)` by checking of it's a list or not and use the same procedure as you are creating to do the reverse on the element as well. Other than that it's very similar.

Comment: I change my code to try to implement what you were saying, however, I don't think I understood it completely. I edited my orginal question to include the new code.

Comment: @sara You cannot just replace `append` with `cons`. You need an accumulator like in my example where i make the helper procedure `loop` with the arguments `lst` and `result`.